# How can I define a variable so it will be treated as a real number?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, education

I want to define a variable like `d` as a Real variable and then using that in the other equation like that:

$\qquad d$ is Real
$\qquad f = 5 + (1 + i) d$

But *Mathematica* gives me this result:

```
d ∈ Reals;
f = d (1 + I) + 5;
Re[f]
```

> ```
> 5 + Re[(1 + i) d]
> ```

But the result should be

> ```
> 5 + d
> ```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15):

In Mathematica, assumptions are not bound to variables itself. You can use `$Assumptions` or you can use the option `Assumptions` to certain functions, which will then try to incorporate the knowledge into their result. Some functions like `Simplify` let you specify assumptions directly as an argument.

See the following:

```
Simplify[Re[f]]
(* 5 + Re[(1 + I) d] *)

Simplify[Re[f], Element[d, Reals]]
(* 5 + d *)

$Assumptions = Element[d, Reals];
Simplify[Re[f]]
(* 5 + d *)
```

`ComplexExpand` assumes that all free variables are real and works in your case too

```
ComplexExpand[Re[f]]
(* 5 + d *)
```